# name does not exist in current content

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Getting an error in Visual Studios (C#) as well with Unity as well:

Error: The name 'Rotate' does not exist in the current context....

Confused as to why it can't be declared in the Update Method, what am I missing from my script even though it is declared above?

```
void Rotation()
{
    Matrix3x3 Rotate(float angle)
    {
        // Create a new matrix
        Matrix3x3 matrix = new Matrix3x3();

        // Set the rows of the matrix

        matrix.SetRow(0, new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle), -Mathf.Sin(angle), 0.0f));

        matrix.SetRow(1, new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angle), Mathf.Cos(angle), 0.0f));

        matrix.SetRow(2, new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        //Return the matrix
        return matrix;
    }
}


void Update()
{
    // Get the vertz from the matrix
    Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;

    // Get the rotation matrix
    Matrix3x3 M = Rotate(angle * Time.deltaTime);

    // Rotate each point in the mesh to its new position
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        vertices[i] = M.MultiplyPoint(vertices[i]);
    }

    // Set the vertices in the mesh to their new position
    mesh.vertices = vertices;

    // Recalculate the bounding volume
    mesh.RecalculateBounds();
}
```

Comment: That's a local function.

Comment: why did you decide to implement it inside `Rotation` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you declared `Rotate` as an inner method. This way it is only locally known inside the method `Rotation`. Put it out of `Rotation` on class level and it will work:

```
class YourClass
{    
    Matrix3x3 Rotate(float angle)
    {
        // Create a new matrix
        Matrix3x3 matrix = new Matrix3x3();

        // Set the rows of the matrix

        matrix.SetRow(0, new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle), -Mathf.Sin(angle), 0.0f));

        matrix.SetRow(1, new Vector3(Mathf.Sin(angle), Mathf.Cos(angle), 0.0f));

        matrix.SetRow(2, new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        //Return the matrix
        return matrix;    
    }

    void Update()
    {    
        // Get the vertz from the matrix
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;

        // Get the rotation matrix
        Matrix3x3 M = Rotate(angle * Time.deltaTime);

        // Rotate each point in the mesh to its new position
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            vertices[i] = M.MultiplyPoint(vertices[i]);
        }

        // Set the vertices in the mesh to their new position
        mesh.vertices = vertices;

        // Recalculate the bounding volume
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ty now I don't have to slam my head into my keyboard anymore